# Fixed Length Regex Required?

Tags: c#, python, regex, lookbehind

I have this regex that uses forward and backward look-aheads:

```
import re
re.compile("<!inc\((?=.*?\)!>)|(?<=<!inc\(.*?)\)!>")
```

I'm trying to port it from C# to Python but keep getting the error

```
look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

Is it possible to rewrite this in Python without losing meaning?

The idea is for it to match something like

```
<!inc(C:\My Documents\file.jpg)!>
```

**Update**

I'm using the lookarounds to parse HTTP multipart text that I've modified

```
body = r"""------abc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

<!inc(C:\Temp\file.txt)!>
------abc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile2"; filename="pic.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<!inc(C:\Temp\pic.png)!>
------abc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="note"

this is a note
------abc--
"""

multiparts = re.compile(...).split(body)
```

I want to just get the file path and other text when I do the split and not have to remove the opening and closing tags

Code brevity is important, but I'm open to changing the `<!inc(` format if it makes the regex doable.

Comment: Have you tried using a raw string? `re.compile(r'''regex here''')`

Comment: "backward lookahead". You mean a lookbehind.

Comment: You can use the [regex module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) instead of the standard re, which does support variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: Apparently you are looking for the `<!inc(` and `)!>` parts. Why are you not looking for the file part with `(?<=<!inc\().*?(?=\)!>)`?

Comment: @thg435 - Sorry, this will be used on other's computers and I don't want to have to distribute an additional module if possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - See my update, sorry for not explaining better in the first place.

Comment: @C0deH4cker - Thanks for the tip, that will make the code nicer to look at!

Comment: You want to **capture** the file path, and everything except the opening `<!inc(` and closing `)!>` tags?

Comment: @ohaal - Yes, exactly and I want them to be split so I have an array of "everythings" and "file paths"... and no opening or closing tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For paths + "everything" in the same array, just split on the opening and closing tag:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'''<!inc\(|\)!>''')
awesome = p.split(body)
```

You say you're flexible on the closing tags, if `)!>` can occur elsewhere in the code, you may want to consider changing that closing tag to something like `)!/inc>` (or anything, as long as it's unique).

[**See it run.**](http://codepad.org/52qAa0Xc)

Comment: +1 :: Optionally replace `.*?` with `.+?` for non-blank inside match

Comment: @user1215106: That wouldn't match his already existing regex. Keep in mind this is a port from C# to Python.

Comment: That's why I wrote **optionally** and explain what would change, Sir.

Comment: BTW :: For better performance, don't use `*?` or `+?` at all, if you don't have to...

Comment: Just google for that - for example: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance

Comment: Sorry - I should have explained better - see my updated question.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think I'll take this approach.  It does lose some accuracy since it doesn't verify the matching end tags, but I'm not too worried about that being a problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

`(?<!...)`

Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for .... This is called a negative lookbehind assertion. Similar to positive lookbehind assertions, the contained pattern *must only match strings of some fixed length*. Patterns which start with negative lookbehind assertions may match at the beginning of the string being searched.

`(?<=...)`

Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position. This is called a positive lookbehind assertion. (?<=abc)def will find a match in abcdef, since the lookbehind will back up 3 characters and check if the contained pattern matches. The contained pattern *must only match strings of some fixed length*, meaning that abc or a|b are allowed, but a* and a{3,4} are not. Note that patterns which start with positive lookbehind assertions will not match at the beginning of the string being searched; you will most likely want to use the search() function rather than the match() function:

Emphasis mine.  No, I don't imagine you can port it to Python in it's current form.

Comment: Yeah, I read the documentation and was hoping someone on SO is smart enough to help me rewrite this without the lookarounds since the documentation says they're not allowed.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Lookarounds".

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pat = re.compile("\<\!inc\((.*?)\)\!\>")

f = pat.match(r"<!inc(C:\My Documents\file.jpg)!>").group(1)
```

results in `f == 'C:\My Documents\file.jpg'`

**In response to Jon Clements:**

```
print re.escape("<!inc(filename)!>")
```

results in

```
\<\!inc\(filename\)\!\>
```

Conclusion: `re.escape` seems to think they should be escaped.

Comment: Any reason to escape `<`,`!` and `>` ? The compile statement should traditionally be an r'' str

Comment: 11 years later: In Python 3.7 (which [reached its EOL](https://devguide.python.org/versions/) just a few months ago) and later, `!`, `"`, `%`, `'`, `,`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `@`, and `\`` are no longer escaped. That said, `<!inc\(filename\)!>` is sufficient.