# Regular Expression to find postfix but ignore a specify prefix

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regex which identifies all words of the form: `xxxxBlah`

but to ignore a specific case of: `SpecialBlah`

Is there any simple way to express this as a regular expression?

Comment: yes if the language of your choice support [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version without negative lookbehind:

```
(?!SpecialBlah\b)\b\w+Blah\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9AGLuG5pn8ndloRX)

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wY1eS1/2)

Comment: No; it makes no difference where the first `\b` is.

Comment: I think there is no need to add `\b` if `\w` is already used that looks for word boundary automatically.

Comment: @Braj Yes, you do need the `\b`. Otherwise, it matches `pecialBlah` in `SpecialBlah`. It also would see `SpecialBlahs` as a match, because it isn't forced to match the trailing word break.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the larguage/IDE/tool you're using, this should work:

```
\w+(?<!Special)Blah
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OJuwgHPS1_-hQ7Me)

It uses a [negative look-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197672). So it finds any [word-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874899) before "Blah", as long as it's not "Special".

Others have provided alternatives when a negative lookbehind is not possible, [such as in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent).

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: negative look-behind is very rarely supported :(