# Regex expression should ignore special characters like punctuation marks

Tags: regex

need a regex exp that check if a word is present in a string(entire word should only be present and not substring in a word)

```
Let a = " raju’s shoes are black"
Let x = "are"
Let regex = new regex("//b"+x+"//b")
regex.test(a).  // returns true which is expected
```

If x is "s", regex.test(a) returns true but should actually be false since s is not a separate word in string a but the regex exp is treating so

How can I fix the regex expression so regex can ignore such special characters or consider only space as between words as new word

Comment: I think you'd first have to fix capital 'Let', strange quotation marks and `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative [lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12210820) and [lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197672) for this:

```
(?<!\S)are(?!\S)
```

Here word will be matched if it surrounded by whitespaces or line boundaries. It is equivalent to `(?<=\s|^)are(?=\s|$)`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/8CFSgb/1).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use boundaries here.

try this one:

```
Let regex = new regex("(^|\s)" + x + "($|\s)")
```

If you want to exclude marks at the end of the word like **black!** you can add `\W` to the end. like this:

```
Let regex = new regex("(^|\s)" + x + "($|\s|\W)")
```

Finally I don't know which language are you using. If it's `JS` you're completely wrong.

The right code in `JS`:

```js
let a = " raju’s shoes are black!"
let x = "black"
let regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+ x +"($|\\s|\\W)");
regex.test(a)
```